# What is the correct way to access endpoints using get_url() or url()?

Tags: python, bottle

i'm using Bottle.
I have defined several routes with their corresponding view function for example

```
/log/<page>
/showlogs
```

How am i supposed to access the endpoints?! Here are the relevant view functions:

```
@app.route( '/log/<page>' )
def log( page ):

@app.route( '/showlogs' )
def showlogs():
```

What is the correct way to access those routes using get_url? I try to:

```
get_url( 'log', page=page )
get_url( 'showlogs' )
```

and the error iam receiving is:

```
[Sun Sep 23 00:35:21.013955 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13159] [remote 45.77.155.110:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 766, in get_url
[Sun Sep 23 00:35:21.013971 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13159] [remote 45.77.155.110:50978]     location = self.router.build(routename, **kargs).lstrip('/')
[Sun Sep 23 00:35:21.013975 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13159] [remote 45.77.155.110:50978]   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bottle.py", line 403, in build
[Sun Sep 23 00:35:21.013978 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13159] [remote 45.77.155.110:50978]     if not builder: raise RouteBuildError("No route with that name.", _name)
[Sun Sep 23 00:35:21.013982 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 13159] [remote 45.77.155.110:50978] bottle.RouteBuildError: ('No route with that name.', 'log')
```

Why get_url complains that there are no routes with that name when they are clearly are?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) You haven't shown us your code, so we can't tell you what's wrong with it, but here's a working example of `get_url`. (Note that `get_url` is a method of the `Bottle` class, so you must use it as such.)

```
from bottle import Bottle

app = Bottle()

@app.route('/log/<page>')
def handle_log(page):
    return ['your page was: {}'.format(page)]

@app.route('/showlogs')
def handle_showlogs():
    return ['showing the logs...']

print app.get_url('/showlogs')  # prints "/showlogs"
print app.get_url('/log/<page>', page='123')  # prints "/log/123"
print app.get_url('nope')  # raises RouteBuildError, as expected
```

(2) Your last question,

> How am i supposed to access the endpoints?

makes me wonder if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (because I'm not sure what "access" could mean here).

If it is (in other words: if, now that you know how to successfully call `get_url`, you *still* can't do what you're trying to do), then please resolve this question and simply ask a new question that states your goal; we'll try to help with that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: By reading your answer it seems that i was calling get_url by itself when i ashould have used app.get_url. But now that get_url can be found i'am receiving the error `bottle.RouteBuildError: ('No route with that name.', 'log')` I have updated the code for you to see.

Comment: Pay close attention to how I'm calling `get_url`, and you'll see how it's different from how you're calling it. `app.get_url('/log/<page>', page='123')`.  Note the slashes.

Comment: Ah , yes indeed! I was get carried away by when i was using flask because in Flask i used to url_for('log', page=123). I was under the impression that get_url was working in the same manner. Why 'app' in front is necessary?

Comment: Happy it helped! `app.` is necessary because `get_url` is a method of the `Bottle` class. https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.get_url

Comment: is it ok to use 'app.url()' instead ?!

Comment: Is `url` even a method on `Bottle`? (I don't recall seeing such a method.) But I'm confused by your question, because if `get_url` is working for you, then why do you want to call `url` instead?

Comment: I was reasinf some other post here on the forum, that people used url() in some cases instead of get_url. url() exists too and it is a method as well.

Comment: Actully get_url still does NOT  work it gives me an error stating `NameError: name 'app' is not defined` I'm defining app though `application = Bottle()
app = application
app.debug = True`

Comment: [No, it's not.](https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.BaseRequest.url) `url` is an attribute (not method) of the `Request` (not `Bottle`) class. I suggest that you read point #2 in my answer (XY problem). If you tell us what you're trying to do (in a new question would be best), we can help you with /that/ (instead of with specifically getting `get_url` to work - which apparently has not solved your problem (XY))

Comment: My advice is: create a new question, where you (1) ask how to achieve your end goal, (2) include your actual code (a minimal example that reproduces the problem), (3) include the results/output you expect, and (4) include the output/results you're actually seeing. If you post a link to your new question here, I'll be happy to take a shot at helping you with that too. :-)

Comment: No need to open a new thread its just that in my 'index.html' template if i try to use `<a href="{{ get_url('showlogs') }}"><img src="/static/img/arrow.gif">` i get `NameError: name 'get_url' is not defined` How should get_url called from within a template?!